# Why PictureBox doesnt appears after position it in a form?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I've got this class fish and I just want to initialize my form with 8 types of fish positioning it in the form. When I run my code the eight fishes never appear. In some case one, two, or three. But when I debug the code the eight fishes appear.

I really don't know what is happening. Hope you could help me to find an answer.

```
class Fish : Aquaticanimal   
{
    private int x;

    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { x = value; }
    }

    private int y;

    public int Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set { y = value; }
    }

    public Fish(Bitmap fish,Form form)
    {
        quantity++;
        aquaticAnimal.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        aquaticAnimal.Image = fish;
        aquaticAnimal.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        positioning(form);
    }

    private void positioning(Form form)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int FormWidth= Convert.ToInt32( form.Size.Width.ToString());
        int FormHeight = Convert.ToInt32(form.Size.Height.ToString());
        aquaticAnimal.Parent=form;
        aquaticAnimal.Top = rnd.Next(200, FormHeight - 100);
        aquaticAnimal.Left = rnd.Next(0, FormWidth - 100);
        this.x = aquaticAnimal.Top;
        this.y = aquaticAnimal.Left;
    }
}
```

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap[] images = new Bitmap[8];
    images[0] = Pecera.Properties.Resources.Nemo;
    images[1] = Pecera.Properties.Resources.Pez_hembra;
    images[2] = Pecera.Properties.Resources.Pez_macho;
    images[3] = Pecera.Properties.Resources.tiburon_adulto;
    images[4] = Pecera.Properties.Resources.Tiburon_bebe_hembra;
    images[5] = Pecera.Properties.Resources.tiburon_macho;
    images[6] = Pecera.Properties.Resources.Dorys;
    images[7] = Pecera.Properties.Resources.tiburon_hembra;

    Fish[] fish = new Fish[8];
    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
    {
        fish[x] = new Fish(images[x], this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of creating a new instance of `Random` extremely quickly, resulting in not-so-random values. Your fishes are all overlapping each other, because the "random" values are the same.

You'll have to refactor your code in such a way that you only use a single instance of `Random`.

Here's my suggestion, changing as little of your code as possible:

```
class Fish : Aquaticanimal
{
    ...
    ...

    private static Random rnd = new Random();

    private void positioning(Form form)
    {
        int FormWidth= Convert.ToInt32( form.Size.Width.ToString());
        int FormHeight = Convert.ToInt32(form.Size.Height.ToString());
        aquaticAnimal.Parent=form;
        aquaticAnimal.Top = rnd.Next(200, FormHeight - 100);
        aquaticAnimal.Left = rnd.Next(0, FormWidth - 100);
        this.x = aquaticAnimal.Top;
        this.y = aquaticAnimal.Left;
    }
}
```

FWIW, your Fish class really shouldn't be responsible for positioning itself on the Form.

Comment: Adding to that, OP shouldn't `.ToString()` just to convert back to `int`.